# Problem with g_file_test in glib

Tags: c, glib

Im trying to learn glib/gtk. I wrote little code which prints files in directory and assigns "f" if they are normal files or "d" if they are directory. Problem is with if. It always gets false value and appends "f" to file name.

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>

int main()
{
    GDir* home = NULL;
    GError* error = NULL;
    gchar* file = "a";

    home = g_dir_open("/home/stamp", 0, &error);
    while (file != NULL) 
    {
        file = g_dir_read_name(home);
        if (g_file_test(file, G_FILE_TEST_IS_DIR))
        {
            g_printf("%s: d\n", file);
        } else {
            g_printf("%s: f\n", file);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g_dir_read_name` returns just the directory/file name. You need to build full path in order to test it using `g_file_test`. You can use `g_build_filename` for that.

```
int main()
{
    GDir* home = NULL;
    GError* error = NULL;
    gchar* file = "a";

    home = g_dir_open("/home/stamp", 0, &error);
    while (file != NULL) 
    {
        file = g_dir_read_name(home);

        gchar* fileWithFullPath;
        fileWithFullPath = g_build_filename("/home/stamp", file, (gchar*)NULL);
        if (g_file_test(fileWithFullPath, G_FILE_TEST_IS_DIR))
        {
            g_printf("%s: d\n", file);
        }
        else
        {
            g_printf("%s: f\n", file);
        }
        g_free(fileWithFullPath);
    }
    g_dir_close( home );
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `g_free(fileWithFullPath);`.

Comment: I think g_dir_read_name returns `const gchar *` so `gchar* file = "a";` should be `const gchar *file = "a";`...  or at least that was what got my compiler to stop warning.